# Raspberry Pi Multiple I2C Busses

Tags: i2c, config.txt

EDIT: Other people I've talked to and one poster here (since deleted) have said that they have the same issue while going through [the Instructables tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/) to set up multiple I2C busses.  There are also multiple comments on the Instructables describing the same issue.  So something is wrong with the tutorial.  As of now, I can't find any other tutorials explaining how to set up multiple I2C busses on the Raspberry Pi.

---

I am trying to connect multiple Vl6180x sensors to my Raspberry Pi 3.  The addresses of these sensors are 0x29 (unchangeable) so unless I use a mux, I have to set up multiple I2C busses.  I followed the instructions detailed in [this](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/) tutorial to do so, but when I run "sudo i2cdetect -y 3" it just checks the addresses really slowly and does not find anything on 0x29.  Yes, I connected SDA to 23 and SCL to 24.  Yes, I tested it on bus 1 and it worked. 
 I am also using 2.2k pullup resistors on both sda and scl.  I2C is not blacklisted and here is my config file:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835) dtparam=audio=on
# --- added by adafruit-pitft-helper Wed Apr 24 16:27:14 HDT 2019 ---
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=i2c1=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay=pitft28-resistive,rotate=90,speed=64000000,fps=30
# --- end adafruit-pitft-helper Wed Apr 24 16:27:14 HDT 2019 ---
enable_uart=1

dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=3,i2c_gpio_delay_us=2,i2c_gpio_sda=23,i2c_gpio_scl=24

dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=4,i2c_gpio_delay_us=2,i2c_gpio_sda=17,i2c_gpio_scl=27
```

Here is a picture of the sensor on i2c bus 1, and the address is properly detected:

[image]

[image]

And here is a picture of the sensor connected to my created i2c bus 3 (SDA=23, SCL=24):

[image]

[image]

So why isn't this working?

---

EDIT: The device is detected on I2C bus 4:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 3
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- ^C
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 4
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 29 -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

And here is the output of "i2cdetect -l":

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -l
i2c-3   i2c         i2c@4                               I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         bcm2835 I2C adapter                 I2C adapter
i2c-4   i2c         i2c@3                               I2C adapter
```

Comment: A clear photo of the wiring may help.

Comment: Added some photos, though I don't think my wiring is off.

Comment: The photo seems to show pins 14/16 being used rather than pins 16/18.

Comment: Sorry, it was just a bad angle.  It is actually pins 16/18 (I updated the photo to show this better).

Comment: Use https://pinout.xyz to help identify the pins on your RPi.

Comment: Dougie - thanks for the tip.  I think my wiring checks out, as pinout.xyz lists pin 16 and 18 (the pins to which my device is connected) as GPIO 23 and 24 -- the same pins that I2C bus 3 is supposed to be using.

Comment: Please post actual circuit diagrams, not photos.

Comment: Posting videos is bad, posting videos where you are not even keeping the camera steady is just plain rude.

Comment: I gave up.  The OP is asking for a pink unicorn, not a black swan.  I also want to see the pink unicorn.  Can I chip in 100 more reputation points?

Comment: From comment by @JacoSlabbert: Also provide your output when you run

`sudo i2cdetect -l`

Comment: As a side note, the sensor itself *does* support changing the address (as per ST application note [AN4478](https://www.st.com//resource/en/application_note/dm00114403.pdf)) by controling the boot up of the sensors using the `!RESET` and `INT` lines but these do not seem to available on the module you're using.

Comment: @RogerJones - they actually are available, and pulling gpio0 low does indeed disable the module so the address of other modules can be changed.  It seems this issue has been solved, however, so I will just go with the multiple busses.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you are using an updated operating system

Check out https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=205576
It is clear that there were some successes. For me it worked perfectly.

What happens if you run i2cdetect -y 4 (Do not change your wiring, it seems like bus numbering is swap around in the new kernel)?
What happens if you run i2cdetect -l?

Play around with the i2c_gpio_delay_us= setting.

Also check the info on the i2c-gpio in boot/overlays/README

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks - I ran i2cdetect -y 4 and it was detected on that bus!  Very weird.  Does this mean I have to use bus 4 to interact with this device even if it is on SDA=23 and SCL=24?  Does the wiring for bus 4 connect to bus 3?  I added the output of i2cdetect -l in my question, if that helps.

Comment: Yes. Tnx for the feedback. The weird problem is that the i2c-gpio kernel module was changed after I wrote the original intractable.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue described on [instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/) about the buses ordering during the definition in the `config.txt` file.

> Never use bus 0 and 2, it is use for other things in the board like
>   EPROM on hats etc
>
> For the April 2019 Raspbian release:
>
> You should always start with the highest bus (Bus 4 in case of two buses) in
>   your config.txt and work through to the lowest bus (bus 3).
>
> The lowest bus must always be bus 3
>
> If you need 5 extra buses, the buses must be in the order of 7, 6, 5,
>   4, 3

Answer (score 1):

**I have it working.....**

Rpi 4 2Gb raspbian lite

in config.txt

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on    
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=4,i2c_gpio_sda=17,i2c_gpio_scl=27    
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=23,i2c_gpio_scl=24
```

note no bus parm needed for bus 1, if you set bus parm (bus=3) 
i2cdetect -y 3 will show the slow info but not your device{s) i2cdetect -y 1 will